# what type of "make" is this?

Tags: bash, makefile

Sorry for the stupid question. This "make" is used at work, but they can't tell me exactly what version it is. Where can I get documentation for it?
Here is example of code:

```
type = "rnd"        #Default test. It's also possible to run "snr" test.

TEST = \
    -L demoduli \
    -L ${DEF_LIB} \
    -sv_seed ${CONFIG_SV_SEED} \
    ${DEF_LIB}.tb_qi_qu_qa \
    +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_NONE \
    +UVM_TESTNAME=tb_qi_qu_qa_${type}_test \
    -do "waves/wave.do" \
    -do "run -all" \
    -do "quit"

base_run_sim:
    vsim -64 -c -voptargs="+acc" \
    ${TEST}
```

For example, I want to add if-else statement in this code. This code doesn't work:

```
type = "rnd"        #Default test. It's also possible to run "snr" test.
type_num = 0        #0 for "rnd" and 1 for "snr"

TEST = \
    -g TEST_TYPE=${type_num} \
    -L demoduli \
    -L ${DEF_LIB} \
    -sv_seed ${CONFIG_SV_SEED} \
    ${DEF_LIB}.tb_qi_qu_qa \
    +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_NONE \
    +UVM_TESTNAME=tb_qi_qu_qa_${type}_test \
    -do "waves/wave.do" \
    -do "run -all" \
    -do "quit"

base_run_sim:
    if [ ${type} = "snr" ]; then type_num = 1; fi
    vsim -64 -c -voptargs="+acc" \
    ${TEST}
```

I received this message:
if [ snr = "snr" ]; then type_num = 1; fi
/bin/sh: 1: type_num: not found

My version:
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: The first piece of makefile has nothing unusual about it. It looks like your command is just wrong, try running it in a shell (in `sh`, which is what Make uses by default).

Comment: Did you forget the tab before the start of your `if` statement?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Also show the output of `make --version`.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: you can't just plop `if [ ${type} = "rnd" ]; then echo "yeee"; fi` at the top level of the makefile. It has to be in a recipe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It works, thank you very much! But I have one more little problem ;) I have updated the question.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between Make variables and shell variables. If you're trying to modify Make variables, you can't do it from shell commands. Read about `ifeq`, and place one in the global scope outside of recipes.

Comment: If I give you an arbitrary executable, there is no unique way to deduce what "version" this executable is. You can hope that the programmer provided an easy to remember way to print the version. GNU has the convention that `--version` shows it, but other implementors might use a different flag. If you are working in a company, where the IT can't even find out, what programs they have installed, perhaps you could already look for a job change to a more professional workplace ...

Answer (score 3):

You can find out what version of make you're using usually by running `make --version` or `make --help`, or asking your system what package provides the `make` program.  Since you didn't give us any details about your operating system or anything else there's little else we can say.  The makefile you post seems to be pretty straightforward POSIX-compliant `make` so this could be a number of different `make` implementations.

However, your problem is not make at all.  It's that your shell script is invalid shell syntax.  If you had provided us with (a) what change you actually made (you say you added that line but you didn't show *where* you added it) and (b) what error you got when you tried to run `make`, it would be quite obvious.

In the shell, the `[` is an actual program that tests things, so you have to be sure it's separated from its arguments by whitespace.  Just like you can't say `lsfoo` to `ls` the file `foo`, you can't say `[${type}`.

Also you're missing a semicolon before the `fi`.

If you'd shown us the command line make printed, then you copy and pasted that same line at your shell prompt, you'd have seen you'd get the same error there, without make involved.

You want:

```
if [ "${type}" = "rnd" ]; then echo "yeee"; fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated my question and clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

`make` is not a shell script language, so you cannot just throw in a shell script line.

The basic idea of `make` is that you want to make something (for example: a program). That something depends on a list of other things, and there is a way to create it from those other things, a recipe. For example:

```
something: main.o other.o
    cc -o something main.o other.o

main.o: main.c
    cc -c main.c

other.o: other.c
    cc -c other.c
```

(note: tabs before the `cc`, not spaces).

The idea is, that `make` goes through the list of dependencies to see if anything changed, and do only the required actions. So if you update only `other.c`, `make` will not rebuild `main.o`.

All the rest that you see in your `Makefile` is just defining two variables `type` and `TEST`, which are used later, f.e. as `$(TEST}`